# Java - Invalid maximum heap size

Tags: jvm, jvm-arguments, heap-size

When running project from IntelliJ IDEA I set VM options `-XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xmx=256m -Xms=256m` and get the following error

> Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
>   Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
>   Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx=256m

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Remove the equals sign after `Xmx` and `Xms`.

Correct VM options: `-XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xmx256m -Xms256m`.